# How to change anchor <a> style when it's in table cell using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have following problem need to change style of  which is in table cell using jQuery. The change is dependable on value in other cell.
I have following table:

```
                             <table id="table">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <a href="www.google.pl">YYYYYYYYY</a></td>
                                    <td>HHHHHHH<td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Jedi Armor1</td>
                                    <td>HHHHHHH</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Jedi Armor2</td>
                                    <td>HHHHHHH</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
```

jQuery method:

```
            $(document).ready(function() {

                $('#table tr td').each(function(){
                     var textValue = $(this).text();
                        if(textValue == 'HHHHHHH'){
                        // add css class or any manipulation to your dom.
                    $(this).parent().css('color','red');
                    $(this).parent().children('td a').css('color','red');
                    };
                });

            // koniec funkcji hover
        });
```

The problem is how to change  style??

Comment: How to change the style of anchor inside table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`children()` can't look 2 levels down

Change:

```
$(this).parent().children('td a')
```

to

```
$(this).parent().find('a');
```

But simplest would be to just add a class to the row and use css to adjust the style for the whole row. It's generally easier to switch classes than undo inline css

```
$(this).parent().addClass('has_H');
```

CSS

```
tr.has_H, tr.has_H a{
    color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code will work if you change `children` to `find`.

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e14qt465/) for a demo